# C# ASP,NET WebForms Заполнение полей html формы

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms, webforms

Есть ли какая то возможность инициализировать значение полей стандартных HTML-контролов из C# кода в момент загрузки страницы?

такие как

```
<select class="form-control" id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
    <option selected>val1</option>
    <option>val2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? `runat="server"` и вперед...

Comment: При том, `runat="server"` используется как и в стандартных элементах `html`, так и в элементах `<asp:...>`. Если убрать у `<asp:...>` элемента `runat="server"`, он не перестанет работать, так как, все элементы `asp ` конвертируются в `html` разметку. Попробуйте запустить сайт на `asp.net` и посмотреть `исходный текст`!